# How to remove extra g elements inside svg from plotly chart

Tags: python, svg, charts, plotly, plotly-python

I am plotting chart using `plotly` in python, it gives me the html document and I just render that on front end.

This is my code:

```
 fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
                x=labels,
                y=values,
                mode='lines',
                hovertemplate='%{x}   %{y:.2f}<extra></extra>',
                showlegend=False,
                fill='tozeroy',
                fillcolor='#F6DFCB',
                line=dict(color='#F58320')
            ))

            fig.update_layout(
                **config_dict,
            #    height = 240,
            #       width = None,
                xaxis_title='',
                yaxis_title=' ',
                showlegend=False,
                plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                yaxis=dict(gridcolor='lightgrey'),
                hovermode="x",
            )

            fig.update_xaxes(
                rangeslider_visible=False,
            )
            
            plot_div = plotly.offline.plot(fig, config=dict(
              displayModeBar=False
            ),output_type='div')
            print("plot",plot_div)
            return fig if request.args.get('ext') == 'png' else plot_div
```

The problem is that inside `svg` element there are multiple `g` elements and many of them are empty which is taking space on my page
and I want to remove those `g` elements.

This is the `svg`:

```
<svg class="main-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="267" height="250" style="background: white;"><defs id="defs-eaa9da"><g class="clips"><clipPath id="clipeaa9daxyplot" class="plotclip"><rect width="107" height="70"></rect></clipPath><clipPath class="axesclip" id="clipeaa9dax"><rect x="80" y="0" width="107" height="250"></rect></clipPath><clipPath class="axesclip" id="clipeaa9day"><rect x="0" y="100" width="267" height="70"></rect></clipPath><clipPath class="axesclip" id="clipeaa9daxy"><rect x="80" y="100" width="107" height="70"></rect></clipPath></g><g class="gradients"></g><g class="patterns"></g></defs><g class="bglayer"><rect class="bg" x="80" y="100" width="107" height="70" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 0; stroke-width: 0;"></rect></g><g class="draglayer cursor-crosshair"><g class="xy"><rect class="nsewdrag drag" data-subplot="xy" x="80" y="100" width="107" height="70" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="nwdrag drag cursor-nw-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="60" y="80" width="20" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="nedrag drag cursor-ne-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="187" y="80" width="20" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="swdrag drag cursor-sw-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="60" y="170" width="20" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="sedrag drag cursor-se-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="187" y="170" width="20" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="ewdrag drag cursor-ew-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="90.7" y="170.5" width="85.60000000000001" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="wdrag drag cursor-w-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="80" y="170.5" width="10.700000000000001" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="edrag drag cursor-e-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="176.3" y="170.5" width="10.700000000000001" height="20" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="nsdrag drag cursor-ns-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="59.5" y="107" width="20" height="56" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="sdrag drag cursor-s-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="59.5" y="163" width="20" height="7" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect><rect class="ndrag drag cursor-n-resize" data-subplot="xy" x="59.5" y="100" width="20" height="7" style="fill: transparent; stroke-width: 0; pointer-events: all;"></rect></g></g><g class="layer-below"><g class="imagelayer"></g><g class="shapelayer"></g></g><g class="cartesianlayer"><g class="subplot xy"><g class="layer-subplot"><g class="shapelayer"></g><g class="imagelayer"></g></g><g class="minor-gridlayer"><g class="x"></g><g class="y"></g></g><g class="gridlayer"><g class="x"><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(92.33,0)" d="M0,100v70" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(114.49000000000001,0)" d="M0,100v70" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(136.72,0)" d="M0,100v70" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(158.88,0)" d="M0,100v70" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(181.05,0)" d="M0,100v70" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path></g><g class="y"><path class="ygrid crisp" transform="translate(0,149.15)" d="M80,0h107" style="stroke: rgb(211, 211, 211); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path><path class="ygrid crisp" transform="translate(0,128.31)" d="M80,0h107" style="stroke: rgb(211, 211, 211); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path><path class="ygrid crisp" transform="translate(0,107.46)" d="M80,0h107" style="stroke: rgb(211, 211, 211); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"></path></g></g><g class="zerolinelayer"><path class="yzl zl crisp" transform="translate(0,170)" d="M80,0h107" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2px;"></path></g><path class="xlines-below"></path><path class="ylines-below"></path><g class="overlines-below"></g><g class="xaxislayer-below"></g><g class="yaxislayer-below"></g><g class="overaxes-below"></g><g class="plot" transform="translate(80,100)" clip-path="url(#clipeaa9daxyplot)"><g class="scatterlayer mlayer"><g class="trace scatter trace276454" style="stroke-miterlimit: 2;"><g class="fills"><g><path class="js-fill" d="M107,70L0,70L0,39.27L0.91,39.56L0.97,39.23L1.15,39.15L1.58,39.98L1.76,39.36L1.82,38.94L2.43,37.44L2.61,37.9L2.67,38.52L3.04,37.98L3.28,38.4L3.34,38.69L3.83,39.86L3.95,39.65L4.55,39.11L4.68,38.94L4.8,39.48L4.98,39.81L5.83,42.23L5.95,41.19L6.01,40.86L6.07,41.02L6.5,40.15L6.68,39.9L6.74,39.44L7.1,40.27L7.29,40.23L7.35,41.32L7.53,43.32L7.65,40.82L8.08,41.27L8.14,41.65L8.56,39.98L8.93,40.69L8.99,40.82L9.84,41.07L9.9,40.73L10.14,41.23L10.32,40.73L10.51,39.94L10.63,39.61L10.99,40.4L11.17,39.98L11.36,40.06L12.02,40.9L12.21,40.44L12.27,40.23L12.87,38.44L13.06,37.44L13.12,37.85L13.3,35.98L13.6,36.06L13.66,36.15L14.09,34.56L14.45,35.19L14.51,35.27L15.24,36.73L15.42,36.52L15.61,36.56L15.67,37.1L16.03,36.23L16.27,36.77L16.46,36.65L16.58,37.02L17,35.98L17.06,36.1L17.12,35.94L17.43,36.19L17.49,35.39L17.55,35.19L18.7,33.23L18.83,34.06L19.01,34.02L20.34,37.94L20.4,37.9L20.46,37.69L20.53,37.23L20.77,38.61L20.95,38.19L21.13,38.73L21.31,39.69L21.38,39.61L21.98,38.81L22.17,37.69L22.65,38.31L22.83,38.65L22.89,38.81L23.32,37.9L23.44,38.31L23.5,38.06L23.68,38.15L23.74,37.56L23.8,37.44L23.87,37.1L24.29,36.6L24.53,37.23L24.59,37.6L25.51,39.48L25.57,39.15L26.48,39.23L26.66,40.31L26.9,41.86L27.33,41.11L27.51,40.94L27.93,42.07L28.36,41.52L28.48,41.44L29.76,43.61L29.82,43.61L30.3,42.02L30.67,42.48L30.73,42.82L30.91,43.32L31.15,42.9L31.33,42.19L32.31,41.23L32.37,41.44L32.43,41.61L34.31,38.52L34.37,38.77L34.55,38.61L34.8,39.27L34.86,39.27L34.92,39.48L35.59,37.98L35.71,38.06L35.77,38.15L36.44,39.19L36.5,39.36L36.68,38.73L37.1,39.81L37.29,39.86L37.53,39.02L37.77,40.48L37.83,40.19L37.89,40.61L39.05,48.78L39.47,48.36L39.53,47.53L40.5,44.57L40.69,44.78L40.75,44.94L40.81,44.73L40.93,46.4L41.11,46.44L41.23,47.36L41.66,45.73L41.72,45.57L41.78,45.03L41.96,47.15L42.2,46.78L42.39,46.82L42.57,47.24L42.93,46.4L43.06,46.61L43.66,46.03L44.69,46.4L44.76,46.28L45.61,46.24L45.79,45.03L45.91,44.4L46.46,44.73L46.64,44.86L46.7,45.23L47.12,44.4L47.18,45.03L47.67,45.15L47.73,45.32L48.1,44.78L48.16,43.9L49.37,42.73L49.43,42.82L50.04,42.61L50.1,41.86L50.89,40.86L50.95,40.94L51.01,41.36L51.44,39.77L51.56,40.15L51.74,39.65L53.01,43.07L53.14,42.9L53.2,42.52L53.26,42.69L53.56,41.57L53.68,41.77L53.86,41.69L54.05,41.44L54.41,41.77L54.47,41.61L54.53,41.19L54.71,40.9L54.78,41.4L54.96,41.36L55.14,41.65L55.75,41.27L55.81,41.44L55.99,41.57L56.05,42.11L56.6,41.23L56.66,41.52L56.84,41.82L58.66,42.69L58.72,43.02L59.88,41.57L59.94,41.94L60.24,42.02L61.09,37.6L61.27,38.65L61.33,38.94L61.94,38.06L62,37.98L63.22,35.35L63.28,35.35L63.64,34.23L63.7,31.06L63.82,29.47L64.25,32.18L64.31,32.18L64.49,32.18L65.04,30.48L65.16,31.48L65.34,31.56L65.4,31.85L65.46,30.73L66.01,31.43L66.19,31.56L66.31,32.35L66.68,30.56L66.74,30.68L66.8,30.81L67.65,31.43L67.71,30.98L67.89,30.23L68.32,31.64L68.38,31.6L69.17,28.77L69.29,29.35L69.35,29.68L69.65,28.52L69.77,30.14L70.02,29.85L70.08,30.1L70.87,31.93L71.11,31.48L71.29,31.52L71.78,30.43L71.96,31.27L72.14,31.68L72.33,31.43L72.75,32.06L72.99,32.02L73.11,32.18L73.24,31.6L73.42,31.48L73.48,30.93L74.27,29.81L74.33,30.1L74.51,28.18L74.81,28.6L74.88,30.23L74.94,29.97L75.3,30.81L75.6,30.31L75.67,30.43L75.97,28.18L76.39,29.56L76.45,30.35L76.58,30.23L76.64,30.35L76.82,32.23L77.85,29.47L77.91,29.56L78.09,30.31L79.01,28.64L79.07,27.72L79.86,22.76L79.98,23.35L80.04,23.35L80.28,24.51L80.4,23.22L80.46,23.26L80.64,21.97L80.77,20.8L81.07,21.97L81.13,22.39L82.1,13.92L82.16,15.7L82.35,14.44L82.47,13.92L82.77,16.01L82.83,17.88L83.26,18.72L83.8,14.03L84.05,14.13L84.11,14.44L84.47,15.7L84.65,14.03L84.71,12.67L85.02,4.86L85.56,6.21L85.75,7.67L85.93,3.5L85.99,4.02L86.6,4.33L87.51,16.42L87.63,13.3L87.69,13.09L87.99,10.17L88.42,12.05L88.48,12.99L90.12,26.56L90.18,24.51L90.97,18.34L91.03,17.47L91.76,15.38L91.82,19.38L92.18,21.84L92.61,19.97L92.67,19.18L92.73,17.93L93.15,20.39L93.22,19.38L93.4,20.14L94,23.85L94.25,23.1L94.31,22.26L95.16,25.81L95.28,24.51L95.34,22.85L96.49,19.64L96.56,19.76L96.62,18.72L96.86,18.05L96.92,20.22L97.47,22.09L97.71,21.05L97.77,21.22L99.41,28.89L99.47,27.31L99.83,31.06L100.38,30.77L100.44,30.73L100.68,31.23L100.75,30.02L100.87,30.23L101.05,29.93L101.17,29.47L101.23,30.18L101.72,30.1L101.9,30.18L102.02,30.77L102.38,29.1L102.51,29.43L102.57,29.31L103.42,31.14L103.6,31.85L103.78,31.56L104.15,32.81L104.27,33.23L104.45,34.56L104.69,32.06L104.87,31.43L105.54,34.02L106.15,33.48L106.21,33.14L106.7,30.23L107,30.39" style="fill: rgb(246, 223, 203); fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 0;"></path></g></g><g class="errorbars"></g><g class="lines"><path class="js-line" d="M0,39.27L0.91,39.56L0.97,39.23L1.15,39.15L1.58,39.98L1.76,39.36L1.82,38.94L2.43,37.44L2.61,37.9L2.67,38.52L3.04,37.98L3.28,38.4L3.34,38.69L3.83,39.86L3.95,39.65L4.55,39.11L4.68,38.94L4.8,39.48L4.98,39.81L5.83,42.23L5.95,41.19L6.01,40.86L6.07,41.02L6.5,40.15L6.68,39.9L6.74,39.44L7.1,40.27L7.29,40.23L7.35,41.32L7.53,43.32L7.65,40.82L8.08,41.27L8.14,41.65L8.56,39.98L8.93,40.69L8.99,40.82L9.84,41.07L9.9,40.73L10.14,41.23L10.32,40.73L10.51,39.94L10.63,39.61L10.99,40.4L11.17,39.98L11.36,40.06L12.02,40.9L12.21,40.44L12.27,40.23L12.87,38.44L13.06,37.44L13.12,37.85L13.3,35.98L13.6,36.06L13.66,36.15L14.09,34.56L14.45,35.19L14.51,35.27L15.24,36.73L15.42,36.52L15.61,36.56L15.67,37.1L16.03,36.23L16.27,36.77L16.46,36.65L16.58,37.02L17,35.98L17.06,36.1L17.12,35.94L17.43,36.19L17.49,35.39L17.55,35.19L18.7,33.23L18.83,34.06L19.01,34.02L20.34,37.94L20.4,37.9L20.46,37.69L20.53,37.23L20.77,38.61L20.95,38.19L21.13,38.73L21.31,39.69L21.38,39.61L21.98,38.81L22.17,37.69L22.65,38.31L22.83,38.65L22.89,38.81L23.32,37.9L23.44,38.31L23.5,38.06L23.68,38.15L23.74,37.56L23.8,37.44L23.87,37.1L24.29,36.6L24.53,37.23L24.59,37.6L25.51,39.48L25.57,39.15L26.48,39.23L26.66,40.31L26.9,41.86L27.33,41.11L27.51,40.94L27.93,42.07L28.36,41.52L28.48,41.44L29.76,43.61L29.82,43.61L30.3,42.02L30.67,42.48L30.73,42.82L30.91,43.32L31.15,42.9L31.33,42.19L32.31,41.23L32.37,41.44L32.43,41.61L34.31,38.52L34.37,38.77L34.55,38.61L34.8,39.27L34.86,39.27L34.92,39.48L35.59,37.98L35.71,38.06L35.77,38.15L36.44,39.19L36.5,39.36L36.68,38.73L37.1,39.81L37.29,39.86L37.53,39.02L37.77,40.48L37.83,40.19L37.89,40.61L39.05,48.78L39.47,48.36L39.53,47.53L40.5,44.57L40.69,44.78L40.75,44.94L40.81,44.73L40.93,46.4L41.11,46.44L41.23,47.36L41.66,45.73L41.72,45.57L41.78,45.03L41.96,47.15L42.2,46.78L42.39,46.82L42.57,47.24L42.93,46.4L43.06,46.61L43.66,46.03L44.69,46.4L44.76,46.28L45.61,46.24L45.79,45.03L45.91,44.4L46.46,44.73L46.64,44.86L46.7,45.23L47.12,44.4L47.18,45.03L47.67,45.15L47.73,45.32L48.1,44.78L48.16,43.9L49.37,42.73L49.43,42.82L50.04,42.61L50.1,41.86L50.89,40.86L50.95,40.94L51.01,41.36L51.44,39.77L51.56,40.15L51.74,39.65L53.01,43.07L53.14,42.9L53.2,42.52L53.26,42.69L53.56,41.57L53.68,41.77L53.86,41.69L54.05,41.44L54.41,41.77L54.47,41.61L54.53,41.19L54.71,40.9L54.78,41.4L54.96,41.36L55.14,41.65L55.75,41.27L55.81,41.44L55.99,41.57L56.05,42.11L56.6,41.23L56.66,41.52L56.84,41.82L58.66,42.69L58.72,43.02L59.88,41.57L59.94,41.94L60.24,42.02L61.09,37.6L61.27,38.65L61.33,38.94L61.94,38.06L62,37.98L63.22,35.35L63.28,35.35L63.64,34.23L63.7,31.06L63.82,29.47L64.25,32.18L64.31,32.18L64.49,32.18L65.04,30.48L65.16,31.48L65.34,31.56L65.4,31.85L65.46,30.73L66.01,31.43L66.19,31.56L66.31,32.35L66.68,30.56L66.74,30.68L66.8,30.81L67.65,31.43L67.71,30.98L67.89,30.23L68.32,31.64L68.38,31.6L69.17,28.77L69.29,29.35L69.35,29.68L69.65,28.52L69.77,30.14L70.02,29.85L70.08,30.1L70.87,31.93L71.11,31.48L71.29,31.52L71.78,30.43L71.96,31.27L72.14,31.68L72.33,31.43L72.75,32.06L72.99,32.02L73.11,32.18L73.24,31.6L73.42,31.48L73.48,30.93L74.27,29.81L74.33,30.1L74.51,28.18L74.81,28.6L74.88,30.23L74.94,29.97L75.3,30.81L75.6,30.31L75.67,30.43L75.97,28.18L76.39,29.56L76.45,30.35L76.58,30.23L76.64,30.35L76.82,32.23L77.85,29.47L77.91,29.56L78.09,30.31L79.01,28.64L79.07,27.72L79.86,22.76L79.98,23.35L80.04,23.35L80.28,24.51L80.4,23.22L80.46,23.26L80.64,21.97L80.77,20.8L81.07,21.97L81.13,22.39L82.1,13.92L82.16,15.7L82.35,14.44L82.47,13.92L82.77,16.01L82.83,17.88L83.26,18.72L83.8,14.03L84.05,14.13L84.11,14.44L84.47,15.7L84.65,14.03L84.71,12.67L85.02,4.86L85.56,6.21L85.75,7.67L85.93,3.5L85.99,4.02L86.6,4.33L87.51,16.42L87.63,13.3L87.69,13.09L87.99,10.17L88.42,12.05L88.48,12.99L90.12,26.56L90.18,24.51L90.97,18.34L91.03,17.47L91.76,15.38L91.82,19.38L92.18,21.84L92.61,19.97L92.67,19.18L92.73,17.93L93.15,20.39L93.22,19.38L93.4,20.14L94,23.85L94.25,23.1L94.31,22.26L95.16,25.81L95.28,24.51L95.34,22.85L96.49,19.64L96.56,19.76L96.62,18.72L96.86,18.05L96.92,20.22L97.47,22.09L97.71,21.05L97.77,21.22L99.41,28.89L99.47,27.31L99.83,31.06L100.38,30.77L100.44,30.73L100.68,31.23L100.75,30.02L100.87,30.23L101.05,29.93L101.17,29.47L101.23,30.18L101.72,30.1L101.9,30.18L102.02,30.77L102.38,29.1L102.51,29.43L102.57,29.31L103.42,31.14L103.6,31.85L103.78,31.56L104.15,32.81L104.27,33.23L104.45,34.56L104.69,32.06L104.87,31.43L105.54,34.02L106.15,33.48L106.21,33.14L106.7,30.23L107,30.39" style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; fill: none; stroke: rgb(245, 131, 32); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2px; opacity: 1;"></path></g><g class="points"></g><g class="text"></g></g></g></g><g class="overplot"></g><path class="xlines-above crisp" d="M0,0" style="fill: none;"></path><path class="ylines-above crisp" d="M0,0" style="fill: none;"></path><g class="overlines-above"></g><g class="xaxislayer-above"><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="183" data-unformatted="2019" data-math="N" transform="translate(92.33,0) rotate(90,0,177)" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;">2019</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="183" data-unformatted="2020" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(114.49000000000001,0) rotate(90,0,177)">2020</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="183" data-unformatted="2021" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(136.72,0) rotate(90,0,177)">2021</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="183" data-unformatted="2022" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(158.88,0) rotate(90,0,177)">2022</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="183" data-unformatted="2023" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(181.05,0) rotate(90,0,177)">2023</text></g></g><g class="yaxislayer-above"><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" data-unformatted="0" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,170)" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;">0</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" data-unformatted="10" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,149.15)">10</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" data-unformatted="20" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,128.31)">20</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" data-unformatted="30" data-math="N" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,107.46)">30</text></g></g><g class="overaxes-above"></g></g></g><g class="polarlayer"></g><g class="smithlayer"></g><g class="ternarylayer"></g><g class="geolayer"></g><g class="funnelarealayer"></g><g class="pielayer"></g><g class="iciclelayer"></g><g class="treemaplayer"></g><g class="sunburstlayer"></g><g class="glimages"></g></svg>
```

For example `<g class="glimages"></g>`, I want to remove this element

Comment: You can't make plotly not render those elements as far as I know. The elements are there for a reason however. Plotly might need to refer to them at a later time (When you add certain different types of traces to the plot dynamically for example). I don't know why the chosen design decision was to render these elements up front instead of inserting dynamically when needed. Maybe there's more overhead inserting it dynamically or it is more convenient in some way to render them upfront, I have no idea. Maybe people on the plotly forums know.